# SSMS V17.2 отключение комментария при генерации скриптов

Tags: sql-server

Прошу помощи сообщества в следующем вопросе: как отключить вставку комментария вида:

```
/*    ==Scripting Parameters==

    Source Server Version : SQL Server 2014 (12.0.5511)
    Source Database Engine Edition : Microsoft SQL Server Enterprise Edition
    Source Database Engine Type : Standalone SQL Server

    Target Server Version : SQL Server 2014
    Target Database Engine Edition : Microsoft SQL Server Enterprise Edition
    Target Database Engine Type : Standalone SQL Server
*/
```

при генерации скриптов в SQL Server Management Studio V17.2?
Например при генерации Alter для View очень напрягает удалять этот блок постоянно.

---

**UPD: 09 октября 2017 года вышла новая версия SSMS - 17.3**
Заголовок `==Scripting Parameters==` теперь не добавляется.
За добавление заголовка в новой версии отвечает опция `Include scripting parameters header` по умолчанию опция установлена в `False`
[image: Скриншот опции:]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

На данный момент нельзя убрать, но в следующем релизе SMO/SSMS, по умолчанию это будет отключено (https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/3139328/).

Comment: Спасибо - буду ждать нового релиза, а пока посижу на 2016 версии SSMS